# GoogleCloudMessaging Hello World register

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm pretty new to both java and android development, so hopefully this question is specific enough:
I want to use GoogleCloudMessaging to write a hello world app. For now, I want my app to register with the googleapis server, get a registration ID, and send that to my server. I will worry about the server response later. I will be using the package:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging
```

I'm aware that I need to register my device to the cloud using the following code:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
String registrationId = gcm.register(senderId);
```

My question is where do I call this? In my MainActivity onCreate()? I think I can't do that because it's network IO on the main thread, but if I create an AsyncTask, how do I make it so that my main thread can see my registrationId so I can call the send function later with the ID in it?

(I realize there are ways to do bi-directional messaging through the GCM server, but I still want to know how to do it this way. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must use an AsyncTask,  since the register method is blocking,  and can't be called by the main thread.

You cab save the registration id in shared preferences and access it from anywhere.  See the deno code at the GCM programmers guide.

As for using the send method,  you should only use it for device to cloud messages,  which are messages from your app to your server.  For such messages to reach your server your server must establish a XMPP connection with the GCM server.

For the simpler cloud to device messaging,  you can send messages from your server to your app via the HTTP API .

Comment: Thank you Eran for your response.